# Relative path gets broken

Tags: html

I have a link in home.php and contactUs.php:

```
contact us/contactUs.php
```

From home.php when I click on Contact Us link it works. However, from contactUs.php the link gets broken to:

```
contact us/contact us/contactUs.php
```

so it gets broken when I click Contact Us link. How to go around this problem?

Comment: However, from contactUs.php the redirect url is contactUs.php

Comment: you are absolutely right thanks mohammad

Answer (score 0):

Using relative paths with root might help :

`/contact us/contactUs.php`

Adding a `/` at the start will point you to the root and start from there no matter from any location ^^ Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Just use a relative path with / might probably solve your problem. For example:

```
home.php
/graphics/image.png
/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.php
```